# ProgressBar ontop of TableLayout

Tags: android, progress-bar, visibility, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to put my ProgressBar ontop of a TableLayout.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/bar_Update"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="250dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableLayout    
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="top">    

      <TableRow 
          android:id="@+id/RowTitle" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/Title"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="60px"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="Unterichtsausfall: \n"
          android:textSize="20dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="serif" >
      </TextView>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imgUpdate"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:adjustViewBounds="false"
          android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:src="@drawable/refresh" />

    </TableRow>   

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Im using `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in my code in order to show the Progressbar on top the layout, but it is not working. To display it gone, I am using `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.  What am I doing wrong?
My goal is to get data from the internet. During this time the Spinner is showing. As soon as the Data is fetched it gets displayed in the Table and the Spinner is gone.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should not define padding for all direction.  This link about android visibility can help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor difference between "On Top" and "Above". 'On Top' generally means it covers up the graphics below, as one would usually want to do with a ProgressBar.

'Above', generally means higher towards the top of the screen, so that the ScrollView and the TableLayout would be closer to the bottom of the screen.

If your ProgressBar was 'On Top', then `View.INVISIBLE` would be ok. But, your `ProgressBar` is 'Above' the layout below. Hence, with the way you have implemented, you should probably set it to `View.GONE` in order to hide it.

---

If you want to display the Progress bar 'On Top' of, or 'Over' your layout below, you will have to make the top level layout a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`.

---

Finally, I do not understand what is wrong. What exactly is not working with your Layout or code behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem where my progressbar was being hidden underneath the tablelayout and I managed to correct it and make it become topmost and display on top of a table without being obscurred after some trial and error.

My basic layout needed re-arranging and I placed the progressbar inside an outer layout and the tableLayout inside a nested a layout.
The ordering was also needed where my ProgressBar was after the nested layout containing the Table.

When working It looked something like this....

```
<RelativeLayout....outer layout

    <ScrollView....
    <RelativeLayout....nested layout
         Some TextViews etc...
        <TableLayout.....inside nested layout/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  <ProgressBar....inside outer layout
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```